# Get the page number for a post in a Laravel JSON feed

Tags: ios, json, swift, laravel

I have this Laravel Route for an API to make a Feed for this iOS app, it works by selecting Posts from a table and then dividing the posts in pages, so I send the page number to download the posts, like this:

```
public function feed(){

    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

    if (request()->has('page') && $user != null) {

        $pagesize = 20;

        $query = Posts::join('clase_user', function ($join) {

            $user  = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

            $join->on('clase_user.clase_id', '=', 'posts.clase_id')
                ->where('clase_user.user_id', '=', $user->id);
        })
            ->with('user')
            ->skip(((int)request()->get('page') - 1) * $pagesize)
            ->take($pagesize)->get();

        return $query;
    }else{
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Pagina no especificada'], 500);
    }

}
```

everything works great but the problem is when there are more than 20 new posts some post will be lost in the middle because my iOS code downloads the firs page, if you scroll down it works fine because it continues the page count so like 1,2,3... but like I said when I update if there are more than 20 new post they get lost.

My iOS code to download the posts (Swift 3):

```
func dwonloadPosts(page: Int!){

        let http = "\(Base_URL)\(feed_url)?token=\(userToken.getToken())&page=\(page)"

        self.pyroFire.Download(mod: HTTPMethod.get, URL: http) {

            if let posts = self.pyroFire.getResult()["posts"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{

                var new = true

                for post in posts{

                    if let id = post["id"] as? Int!{

                        var idRow = 0

                        for oldPost in self.Posts{

                            if(oldPost.id == id){

                                new = false

                                if let text = post["text"] as? String!{
                                    self.Posts[idRow].text = text
                                }

                                if let archivo = post["archivo"] as? String!{
                                    self.Posts[idRow].archivo = archivo
                                }

                                if let updated_at = post["updated_at"] as? String!{
                                    self.Posts[idRow].updated_at = updated_at
                                }
                            }

                            idRow += 1
                        }

                        if(new){

                            var NewPost = Post()

                            NewPost.id = id

                            if let user_id = post["user_id"] as? Int!{
                                NewPost.user.id = user_id
                            }
                            if let clase_id = post["clase_id"] as? Int!{
                                NewPost.clase_id = clase_id
                            }
                            if let text = post["text"] as? String!{
                                NewPost.text = text
                            }
                            if let archivo = post["archivo"] as? String!{
                                NewPost.archivo = archivo
                            }
                            if let created_at = post["created_at"] as? String!{
                                NewPost.created_at = created_at
                            }
                            if let updated_at = post["updated_at"] as? String!{
                                NewPost.updated_at = updated_at
                            }


                            if let user = post["user"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{

                                if let name = user["name"] as? String!{
                                    NewPost.user.name = name
                                }
                                if let about = user["about"] as? String!{
                                    NewPost.user.about = about
                                }
                                if let text = user["handler"] as? String!{
                                    NewPost.user.handler = text
                                }
                                if let archivo = user["pp"] as? String!{
                                    NewPost.user.pp = archivo
                                }
                                if let created_at = user["email"] as? String!{
                                    NewPost.user.email = created_at
                                }
                                if let updated_at = user["created_at"] as? String!{
                                    NewPost.user.created_at = updated_at
                                }
                            }

                            self.Posts.append(NewPost)

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        }
        self.collectionV.reloadData()
    }
```

My question is to find a way to send an id of a Post and then get the page number the post belongs so I can update successfully.

If you have a better way to make an even better Feed please feel open to post any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send an `offset` instead of "page number". The you can skip that number of rows when you retrieve the results from your database without harcoding "pageSize". There are multiple approaches to paging and it can actually be quite complex depending on your app/data.

If your `dwonloadPosts(page:)` method is asynchronous, then `self.collectionV.reloadData()` should be after the `for-in`, not outside the network call. Otherwise the collectionView will be reloaded before all or at least some of the new data was appended.

```
func dwonloadPosts(page: Int!) {

    let http = "\(Base_URL)\(feed_url)?token=\(userToken.getToken())&page=\(page)"

    self.pyroFire.Download(mod: HTTPMethod.get, URL: http) {

        guard let posts = self.pyroFire.getResult()["posts"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
            else { return }

        var new = true

        for post in posts {
            ...
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionV.reloadData()
        }
    }

}
```

Notes:

- Variables in Swift usually start with lowercase.
- Read the following Swift style guides for more info:

  - https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/
  - https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide
  - https://github.com/linkedin/swift-style-guide
  - https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide

Comment: Offset in this case means the accumulated result count. E.g: if you asked for 20 rows, the offset will be 20 at first. On the next page, it will be 20 * pageNumber. Here's an overview of how twitter manages pages: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines

Comment: If you are interested in paging strategies, search online (e.g: offset/skip, page token) and have a look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks nathan this is really helpful i'll get reading right now!